# Does a control packet of MQTT Qos 1/2 for the same message id come in only after an acknowledgement?

Tags: mqtt

I'm looking into MQTT v3.1.1 and have the this question:

Can I safely assume that in a connection(**no reconnect**), the sender/receiver 
wouldn't see the next control packet for **the same message identifier** before sending/seeing the acknowledgement?

More precisely, I'm concerned about the following two cases.

[image]

In both cases, I assume:

- The whole conversation remains in the same connection(no reconnect).
- All **PUBLISH#N** share the same message identifier.

I think the re-sent copies of control packets probably don't fit in the
description of [4.4 Message delivery retry](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718103) as there's no reconnect. **Please
correct me if I'm wrong**.

For QoS 1, I'm not sure about **PUBLISH#B** which comes in before sending **PUBBACK**.

Likewise, for QoS 2, I'm not sure about **PUBLISH#2** which comes in before sending
**PUBREC** and **PUBLISH#3** which comes in before seeing **PUBREL**.

Or, I can safely assume this situation should not happen so as it did
happen then I can ignore those re-sent packets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading some implementations and reflecting on this question for a while, I think I might be able to answer it by myself.

The key here is that a connection/socket-pair is **duplex**, meaning that the writing stream and the reading stream are independent and there's no way that content in one stream blocks that in another unless the application logic enforces such order.

A paranoid sender may write consecutive **PUBLISH**s without waiting for **PUBBACK**s, but a receiver that respects the specification is rightly to only fetch one from the TCP buffer, acknowledge a **PUBBACK**, then fetch and acknowledge another one.

Therefore, in the case in Fig 1, **PUBLISH#B** in the eyes of the receiver is just another **PUBLISH** and is processed after sending **PUBACK#A**.

In the case in Fig 2, the receiver responded **PUBLISH#1** with **PUBREC#1**, then it tries to read a **PUBREL** but will instead find **PUBLISH#2** in the buffer, in that situation, the [specification](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718102) states:

> Until it has received the corresponding PUBREL packet, the Receiver
>   MUST acknowledge any subsequent PUBLISH packet with the same Packet
>   Identifier by sending a PUBREC. It MUST NOT cause duplicate messages
>   to be delivered to any onward recipients in this case.

Answer (score 0):

MQTT QOS acknowledgements are **NOT** end to end. They are between the publisher and the broker and then again separately between the broker and the subscriber.

There is no End to End delivery notifications in MQTT as there is no way for a publisher to know if there are 0, 1 or n subscribers to a given topic.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. My question therefore concerns only the conversation between a pair of sender/receiver(one of them is a client, the other is the broker).